# Less than and Greater than producing unexpected results.

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'm new to Javascript, and I'm writing a Chrome extension which manipulates the [Chrome Omnibox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox).

I have the following code implemented:

```
chrome.omnibox.onInputEntered.addListener(
  function(text) {
    console.log('inputEntered: ' + text);
    if (text < 07000000){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:"PRIVATEURL1"+ text});
}
    if (text > 07000000){
    chrome.tabs.create({url:"PRIVATEURL2"+ text});
}
  });
```

Currently, it behaves like this:

Enter 07000001 & be brought to PRIVATEURL2.

Enter 00600000 & be brought to PRIVATEURL1.

Enter 1 & be brought to PRIVATEURL1.

All as expected.

However, enter:

04542226 & be brought to PRIVATEURL2.

06000001 & be brought to PRIVATEURL2.

I don't understand, is 04542226 not < 07000000 and therefore I should be brought to PRIVATEURL1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is rather easy.

Your `text` is, as evident, a string. Say, `"07000001"`. When put in an arithmetical comparison, it's cast to a number. Which number? Let's see:

```
> text
"07000001"
> Number(text)
7000001
```

Now, that's correct. What is not is your number literal, `07000000`

It is more or less known that you can write a hexadecimal number as a literal using the `0x` notation:

```
> 0xFF
255
```

What is *less* known is that `0` prefix is a literal notation for *octal* numbers. 7000000 in base 8 is the number 1835008:

```
> 07000000
1835008
```

So, you should use `7000000` literal instead:

```
> "04542226" < 07000000
false
> "04542226" < 7000000
true
```

---

Curiously, `parseInt`/`Number` will process hexadecimal notation, but as we've seen it ignores leading zeroes. [This is set by ECMAScript 5 standard.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt#Octal_interpretations_with_no_radix)

Note that you can (and should) pass a second argument, radix, to the function if you expect a certain base.

Comment: Your input is a string. Use it as such. `.charAt(N)`, for instance.